How annotate type function?
@classmethod
def get_serializer_class(
    cls,
    skip_hidden: bool = False
) -> type[serializers.Serializer]:
    fields = {}

    for filter_name, filter_field in cls.filters.items():
        if skip_hidden and filter_field.hidden:
            continue
        fields[filter_name] = filter_field.serializer_field

    serializer_class = type(
        f'{cls.__name__}Serializer',
        (cls._meta.serializer_class,),
        fields)
    return serializer_class

What type should I specify for the serializer_class variable?
Now the linter shows an error: Expected type 'Type[Serializer]', got 'type' instead
I tried to specify the type Any, but in my opinion this is the wrong solution

You're trying to assert statically that get_serializer_class will return something that doesn't exist statically. You might try using cast('Serializer', serializer_class) as the return value, to let the type checker you know what you are creating.

type() function

with three arguments, return a new type object. This is essentially a dynamic form of the class statement.
The bases tuple contains the base classes.

ref
type[T] means that the return value is expected to be a type that is a subclass of T.
You have only posted a method code, so I do not know what your meta field holds.
But to make sure that base class is the subclass of serializers.Serializer, You can replace cls._meta.serializer_class with serializers.Serializer in your type function.
@classmethod
def get_serializer_class(
    cls,
    skip_hidden: bool = False
) -> type[serializers.Serializer]:
    fields = {}

    for filter_name, filter_field in cls.filters.items():
        if skip_hidden and filter_field.hidden:
            continue
        fields[filter_name] = filter_field.serializer_field

    serializer_class = type(
        f'{cls.__name__}Serializer',
        (serializers.Serializer,),
        fields)
    return serializer_class


Nope, same error: Expected type 'Type[Serializer]', got 'type' instead

@КонстантинСуворов can you post more of your code? I want to reproduce the issue.
